# Laravel return UserTitle By Count

Tags: php, laravel

On my project I'm tying to generate user titles by users' post, comments, questions and answers count from titles table.

I have titles table which can I add new titles. And each title has own post count. So when  a user has greater or equal post count title will be generated from titles table.

Problem is I can't fetch the greater value in the titles table with users post count. When I use `<=` it shows the title but when I use `>=` it doesn't return anything.

Ps: There aren't any relation between users and titles table. It returns only equal title data.

My codes are below:

```
public function title()
{

    $commentcount = $this->hasMany('App\Comment')
                        ->whereUserId($this- >id)
                        ->count();

    $questioncount = $this->hasMany('App\Question')
                        ->whereUserId($this->id)
                        ->count();

    $answercount = $this->hasMany('App\Answer')
                        ->whereUserId($this->id)
                        ->count();

    $total = $commentcount + $questioncount + $answercount;
    $title = Title::where('postcount', '>=', $total)->first();
    if ($title) {

        $show = '<span class="badge badge-danger rutbe" style="background:' . $title->color . '">' . $title->text . '</span>';
        return $show;
    } else {

        return false;
    }
}
```

I can't figure out why doesn't return anything when greater or equal count.

Comment: Why do you use the relation definition syntax here (`$this->hasMany('App\Comment')`) when you actually want to query the results directly? Are you sure a title for the given data exists? If `<=` works I'd say you just don't have a title that matches the count. You will also not always receive the same title if you don't sort the results by count before selecting the `first` one. Can you `dd` the total value and show the content of your titles table?

Comment: thanks for your reply. 
my titles table like below;
https://hizliresim.com/NL35OP

when i choose <= it return like below;
https://hizliresim.com/kMAjXm

when i choose >= it return like below;
https://hizliresim.com/anjo1O

Bythe way how can i do this in short way?

Comment: When i ordered with post count titles table it worked:) Thanks friend. Bytheway are any shorthand to doing this without more querries like i did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll sum up my answer based on my comment and give the hints with regards to your queries.

Basically the where conditition in your codes matches multiple title entries. Therefore selecting the first will not always match the correct one. As you want to match the "lowest" matching title you probably want to change

```
$title = Title::where('postcount', '>=', $total)->first();
```

to

```
$title = Title::where('postcount', '>=', $total)->orderBy('postCount', 'ASC')->first();
```

Some other enhancement proposals

```
$commentcount = $this->hasMany('App\Comment')
                    ->whereUserId($this- >id)
                    ->count();
```

Seems to be weird to use in your (probably User?) class. You should refactor this to something like

```
public function comments() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
```

This defines your users realtion to his comments. If you now want to have the amount of the users comments in your title function you can simply do

```
$this->comments()->count();
```

When doing this for all 3 of your relations your title method could look like

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}

public function questions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Question');
}

public function answers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Answer');
}

public function title()
{
    $total = $this->comments()->count() + $this->questions()->count() + $this->answers()->count();

    $title = Title::where('postcount', '>=', $total)->orderBy('postcount', 'ASC')->first();

    if ($title) 
        return '<span class="badge badge-danger rutbe" style="background:' . $title->color . '">' . $title->text . '</span>';
    }

    return false;
}
```

This does not only make it look & feel way cleaner - it also helps you with future queries where you handle these relations.

Comment: No problem, hope this helps. If you don't know about it I highly recommend laracast as learning Plattform (https://laracasts.com/). Also feel free to mark this answer as correct if it is the correct solution to your issue.